# any partial outer join available in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, outer-join

I m having null values corresponding to another table in mysql which i m able to select through a query like -

```
SELECT 
    s.*, 
    i.image_id 
FROM image_shout s 
LEFT JOIN images i ON s.image_id = i.image_id 
WHERE i.image_id IS NULL;
```

Now is there any partial outer join available through which i can get the same result like -

```
SELECT 
    s.*, 
    i.image_id 
FROM image_shout s 
LEFT OUTER JOIN images i ON s.image_id = i.image_id;
```

**EDIT-**

I thought there could be anything like **LEFT PARTIAL OUTER JOIN** which selects the rows not in the right table.

Regards

Comment: have you tried just making the condition in the WHERE on the LEFT JOIN?

Comment: I could not get you.. in the first query? there is a where clause

Comment: yea so `LEFT JOIN images i ON s.image_id = i.image_id AND i.image_id IS NULL` and try removing the where

Comment: @JohnRuddell, that doesn't work.. it joins to an empty result set, giving you every `image_shout` row with appended `images` columns all as `null`.

Comment: see my edit in the question

Comment: ok well here is a good visual representation of joins.. this is SQL so the full outer join is not valid for MySQL. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Comment: i think everywhere they use a where clause for this.

Comment: you should too! :) is there any particular reason why you don't want the where?

Comment: i thought if there is any advances in sql joins for that as i wrote in the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, `LEFT JOIN` is synonymous with `LEFT OUTER JOIN`..

You can do it without a `JOIN` and a `NOT IN()` or `NOT EXISTS()` but these can be seen as clunkier and may incur performance penalties.